# Gather result from scalaz stream Process

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

Recently I started using scalaz streams in Scala/Akka.
I'm fetching records from a nosql database. I want to map records to message items (via `translateItem: Item`) and create Packages (1 Package = 100 Items) of them. E.g. there are 500 records.

```
 val readChunks = records.chunk(100)
 val createPackages = readChunks.map(chunk => translateItem(chunk))
                                .map(i => toPackage(i))
 val result = createPackages.runLog.run.toList
```

I've tried to fetch the result (the `List[Package]`) via `runLog`.
The output of the log looks good. But I don't need the logging overhead.

But how to write the result to a list e.g.?

Or I might return a `Future[List[Package]]` and pass it to an Akka actor to fetch (`Await.result`) it. I might convert the scalaz `Task` to a `Future`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "Log" in `runLog` just means that the outputs are collected—it doesn't have much to do with _logging_ in the record keeping sense. You could write a version of `runLog` that collects the outputs into a list, but the performance is going to suffer. If you really want a list, consider `runLog.map(_.toList)`, which gives you a `Task[List[Package]]` that you can convert into a `Future[List[Package]]`.